# Finding a bi-holomorphic transformation

Tags: complex-analysis

I was given at H.W a question to find a bi-holomorphic transformation that maps the set $\{\operatorname{Im}(z)>0\}$ onto the set $\{\operatorname{Im}(z)>0, |z|<1\}$.
We weren't taught, nor do I know any specific algorithm to this sort of questions, so I'm guessing it's all about experience and intuition.
I don't want a solution, but if someone could give me some sort of intuition it would be great!

Comment: I'd start with a Mobius transformation taking $-1$ and $1$ to $0$ and $\infty$ and see what that does to your second set.

Comment: Why'd you start with that?